# InnoSetup: figure out which process is hogging a file and causing access denied

Tags: inno-setup, access-denied

A user is intermittently getting an access denied error when installing our application. Is there any way to make InnoSetup figure out the name of the process hogging the file, similar to the Sysinternals `handle` command and show that in the error message? Could something like that be done using only an install script, or would it require modifying the Innosetup source code?

[image: InnoSetup access denied]

Comment: If you're using the latest version of Inno and the user is running Vista or later then it should normally handle this by default via the Restart Manager -- but only if something is constantly holding the file open (eg. they left your app running).  Other possibilities for this include antivirus programs, which is why it's generally recommended to temporarily disable them when installing software.

Comment: Sure. I'm still looking for an answer to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify the error message above to include that sort of additional information without modifying the Inno source.

There are [other ways](http://rlbyte.com/product-details.php?id=7&show=desc) to perform in-use-files checks prior to the start of the installation, when on pre-Vista PCs.  (I have not used this product myself.)

You're welcome to suggest an enhancement to this error message as an official feature request -- or better yet to write supporting code yourself and submit a pull request on GitHub.